# main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: No element found with ID 'before.body.end'

Tags: magento-2.1, system.log

I got an error

> main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: No element found with ID 'before.body.end'

in the **system.log**. I didn't use this id in anywhere in my custom theme inherited by **Luma**.

Why this error came continuously and how to fix this?

Comment: any advance ? I'm facing the exact same error in system.log using a theme not from Luma and 2.1.9